# IllegalStateException: Failed to load Application Context when using File functions in Java

Tags: java, spring, file, spring-mvc, illegalstateexception

I'm using a function like this to get the latest file present based on timestamp:

`File file = getFile(path);`

Where getFile () is like this:

```
private File getFile (String path) {
File directory = new File(path);
File[] files = directory.listFiles(File::isFile);
long latestVersion = Long.MIN_VALUE;
File latestFile = null;
if (files!= null) {
for (File file : files) {
if (file.lastModified() > latestVersion) {
latestFile = file;
latestVersion = file.lastModified();
}
}
}
return latestFile;
}
```

On running mvn clean install I get this error:

`IllegalStateException: Failed to load Application Context` in a totally different test class of the same module.
If I remove the file method, the build runs fine. Definitely something is wrong here in this code then?
Can anyone help here?

Thanks.

Comment: Please post stacktrace?

Comment: There's is surprisingly no stack trace as when I run just this code in a separate class, the code runs fine and gives me the file. Infact, the test class is also running fine and giving me the file name.